# Google Sign is not working with signed.apk

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Not able to get user details using GoogleSignIn in signed apk,

Locally it gives me the user email-id and id, But in signed apk after selecting gmail account I'am not getting user email-id or details email

I have also verified SHA1 in play console and firebase it is same..

This issue arrived since i have migrated to androidx.

Here is the Code still far i have did, Can any one help me with what should i do?

build.gradle

```
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
```

MainActivty.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = TestGoogle.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 101;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    Button btn_loginin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_loginin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_loginin);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        btn_loginin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });

    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

            // Signed in successfully,

           //Not getting user account details
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();
        mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess();
    }
}
```

Comment: `SHA1` release mode?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya SHA1 in release mode is same in play console, I have verified it.

Comment: please show the logcat with error you are getting

Comment: @UmairIqbal One error i'am getting which is "signInResult:failed code=10" in handleSignInResult()

Comment: Make sure that the build you are testing have the same build version as the one which is live in the playstore

Answer (score 0):

Double check these 3 things closely please :

1 Check GoogleSignInOptions.

2 Package Name in the Google API console and SHA1.

3 The web client ID (if you're using it) belongs to the same project where you registered your package name and SHA1.

Comment: I have check all the three points which you have mentioned, But my issue is not resolved still now I'am facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Open your Google Play account and use SHA1 which is from Google and create new developer I'd and Key on Google api counsel.

We need to create debug and release developer I'd and Key also on Google api counsel.

You already added debug but not release.